# My SQL ログイン時 エラー

Tags: mysql

mysql -h % -uroot  -p でログインするときに

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '%' (0)

が出ます

どうしたら解消できますか ？

Answer (score 1):

権限の付与時に使用する `%` は MySQL におけるワイルドカードを表しているので、接続時に `-h` オプションの引数には `%` ではなく、個別のホスト名やIPアドレスを指定する必要があります。

```
> mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

なお、接続先の MySQL サーバがコマンドを実行するマシン上 (localhost) で動いているなら `-h` オプションは省略可能です。

```
> mysql -u root -p
```

**参考:**
[MySQL サーバーへの接続 | MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/connecting.html)

Comment: へんな「仕様」内容みたいなものが出てしまいます

Comment: %の部分をIPアドレスにして入りました

Comment: max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
compression-algorithms            (No default value)
zstd-compression-level            3
load-data-local-dir               (No default value) このようなエラーが出ます